# Terraform: Using S3 bucket to host remote state file - BucketRegionError: incorrect region

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

The bucket is already created in AWS in the correct region. Using the below provider settings

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "CORRECTACCESSKEYISINHERE"
  secret_key = "CORRECTSECRETKEYISINHERE"
  region ="eu-west-2"
  alias = "regional"
}
```

And here are the S3 backend settings

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    region = "eu-west-2"
    bucket = "red-dwarf-terraform-eu-west-2"
    key    = "terraform-state/red-dwarf/dev/main/terraform.tfstate"
    access_key = "CORRECTACCESSKEYISINHERE"
    secret_key = "CORRECTSECRETKEYISINHERE"
  }
}
```

Keep getting the following error

```
Error refreshing state: BucketRegionError: incorrect region, the bucket is not in 'eu-west-2' region at endpoint ''
        status code: 301, request id: , host id:
```

Have tried deleting the existing .terraform folder, deploying to a completely environment. Nothing works.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "desired-region"
    alias = "regional"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    region = aws.regional
    bucket = "red-dwarf-terraform-eu-west-2"
    key    = "terraform-state/red-dwarf/dev/main/terraform.tfstate"
    access_key = "CORRECTACCESSKEYISINHERE"
    secret_key = "CORRECTSECRETKEYISINHERE"
  }
}
```

Comment: The name of the bucket is as above. Can you clarify what you need if that's not sufficient?

Comment: Bucket name is "red-dwarf-terraform-eu-west-2" or "terraform-state"?

Comment: "red-dwarf-terraform-eu-west-2"

Comment: Then key should be like this : "red-dwarf-terraform-eu-west-2/path-to-file".
Hope this help you.

Comment: The issue is with either the bucket name or key.  All the other things look fine

Comment: Thank you for your help. The engineer who created the bucket put it in the wrong region. He put it in eu-west-1 and told me over and over that's where it was.

I managed to get another engineer to check the location and told me he's done it wrong.

Comment: Happy to help you.
If you have any questions related to terraform with aws you can send me que link. I will try to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I might just do that

Comment: How does this answer answer the question? I'd be tempted to close this as it's not really answerable or it comes down to a misunderstanding or typo that isn't likely to be useful for another user (the error message in the question is significantly clearer than this answer is).

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like this line

```
 key    = "terraform-state/red-dwarf/dev/main/terraform.tfstate"
```

Try this

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    region = "eu-west-2"
    bucket = "red-dwarf-terraform-eu-west-2"
    key    = "(filename)/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

In my environment, we using like this

ex: project(Project name ) folder, inside this folder we have 2 folders (testproject, Jenkins). `backend.tf` file inside testproject folder

Folder structure

```
project
      testproject ---->backend.tf, database.tf, iam.tf, config.tf, .., ...
      Jenkins
```

Terraform file backend.tf

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "bucketname"
    key    = "testproject/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "ap-southeast-2"
  }
}
```

Option 2

removing the .terraform folder and trying `terraform init` again

Comment: This doesn't answer the question either. The OP was looking for a bucket in one region but as the error says it was actually in another region.